# How to extract a particular portion from a multitext fil

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have list of pl no. In a separate file like as follows:

```
Pl:105
Pl:17.3
Pl: 7.2
```

And in a merged text file I have a pattern like :

```
Name :na
Pr: 78
Pl: 7.2
Unit :40
Density:80
7.3
7.8
Name :na
```

From name to next name the pattern is same.

I need to match  the pl no that I have in separate list and extract only those from the entire name till next name to different different text file.

I am unable to do this there almost 4000 pl ids to do it manually is next to impossible.

Comment: Python seems like a good tool for this. What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the expected output for the inputs above? Please add it to the question.

Comment: the expected output is Name :na
Pr: 78
Pl: 7.2
Unit :40
Density:80
7.3
7.8 in a separate text file

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps. 1)Get all the pl values from the pl list 2)Get the values in merged list which are associated with the pl values in pl list. I assume the pattern is same as you provided. 3)Write the found values to txt files with pl as the name.

```
PL_FILE = "pl_file.txt" #Which has the pl file
FULL_FILE = "full_file.txt" #Which has the merged file data

PL_LIST =[] #List that will contain all the pl values
#Loop to get all the required pl values from PL file
with open(PL_FILE) as f1:
    for line in f1:
        if ":" not in line:
            continue
        else:
           PL_LIST.append(line.split(":")[1].strip())

print("pl values found :", PL_LIST) #Gives the list of pl values

REQUIRED_PL_LIST =[]

with open(FULL_FILE) as f2:
    current_list=[]
    for line in f2:
        if "Name" in line:
            if len(current_list)>0: #has some values
                pl_val = current_list[2].split(":")[1].strip() #Gets the pl value
                if pl_val in PL_LIST:# if the pl value is in REQUIRED_PL_LIST , add it
                    REQUIRED_PL_LIST.append(current_list)
            current_list=[line] #Reset temp details
        else:
            current_list.append(line) # otherwise append

print("Associated values found for pl values : ", REQUIRED_PL_LIST)#Assoociated values obtained for pl values in pl list

#Creats text file for each pl values. and save the values. 
for list_write in REQUIRED_PL_LIST :
    file_name = list_write[2].split(":")[1].strip() +".txt"
    with open(file_name, "w") as output:
        for val in list_write:
            output.write(val)
        print("Created file " , file_name)
```

Output :

```
pl values found : ['105', '17.3', '7.2']
Associated values found for pl values :  [['Name :na\n', 'Pr: 78\n', 'Pl: 7.2\n', 'Unit :40\n', 'Density:80\n', '7.3\n', '7.8\n']]
Created file  7.2.txt
```

Comment: print.sh: 1: PL_FILE: not found
print.sh: 2: FULL_FILE: not found
print.sh: 4: PL_LIST: not foundI received an error message that says, "print.sh: 1: PL_FILE: not found, print.sh: 2: FULL_FILE: not found, print.sh: 4: PL_LIST: not found, print.sh: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected." The program was unable to read the PL file, so I'm sending a snapshot of the file that I used.
print.sh: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected I got this error it was unable to read the pl file "I received an error message stating that the program was unable to read the PL file

Comment: You need to replace the file name in PL_FILE = "pl_file.txt" #Which has the pl file
FULL_FILE = "full_file.txt" #Which has the merged file data, with your names.